# How to get easily timestamp in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timestamp, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to get stage or step duration for some jobs in my Jenkins Pipeline.

I have no idea how to get the duration, so I decided to calculate it. For that, I would like to get timestamp with this format : 1624869043 (because it's easier to calculate with this format).

What is the easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [timestamps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/), with **elapsed** option and **precision** milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

just use timestamp option in your pipeline

```
 options { timestamps() }
```

Comment: This option, only enable the output of timestamp in the console?

Comment: I found this :                     def date11= new Date()
                    println date11.getTime()
                    
                    def date22= System.currentTimeMillis()
                    println date22